# Stumped on SQL question regarding type 2 table

Tags: sql

*How many new customers are there every month?*

```
from 
    customer 
where 
    rownum = 1 -- you only want the first time each customer appears in the table 
group by 
    plan_type, month(start_date)
```

Comment: Yes, that should have been pretty close. But you wanted `from C` rather than `from customer` in the outer query. You've also grouped by plan type, which isn't in the accepted answer. I imagine you just added that back in if you did need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like your idea of looking at the first time you've seen a customer. However, I think you just need `min(month)` and there's no need for window functions.

I.e., something like the following will give you the first month each customer appears.

```
SELECT customer_id, MIN(month) AS month FROM transactions GROUP BY customer_id
```

The result of the above query is the first time a customer had made a transaction along with the month of the transaction.

Now you need to group by month and count:

```
SELECT month, COUNT(*) FROM ( 
   SELECT customer_id, MIN(month) AS month FROM transactions GROUP BY customer_id
) GROUP BY month
```

This will group the customers into months. Each customer appears in a single month. So counting the number of customers in each group (a specific month) will return the new customers making transactions in this month.

Comment: im a bit confused. so something like this?
SELECT month, COUNT(*)
FROM(
SELECT customer_id, MIN(month) AS month FROM CustomerInfo GROUP BY customer_id)
GROUP BY month?

Comment: @DrewPham: updated with a bit more information. Why are you confused?

Comment: Could you assist with the following question? Hardest one in this example set.
how many people switch plans per month (month, from plan to plan, # customers)?

Comment: Much harder. Just a thought: Perhaps you can self join the transaction table with itself joining a transaction A with the latest transaction B that happened before A for the same customer but with B.plan <> A.plan. Is this homework/test?

Comment: `select month(start_date), count(distinct customer_id) from customers group by month(start_date) having count(distinct plan_type) > 1`